# Term for advice that cautions against action?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, terminology

I'm polishing my floors, and I've reached a point where I can add another coat or accept it as it is.  As such, I've been having a conversation with myself about whether or not it's advisable to do so.

Is there a term for the types of advice contained in some of my favorite expressions:

> Better is the enemy of good. (Var. *Perfect* is the enemy of good.)
>
> If it ain't broke, don't fix it.
>
> Don’t just do something, stand there.

All three expressions caution you not to take action when inaction may serve you best.  This advice is counter-intuitive at best.  Advice usually encourages you to improve your situation through action, not inaction.

How would you characterize this type of advice?  *Discouraging* seems incorrect as they're not meant to demoralize.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99244/discussion-on-question-by-david-m-term-for-advice-that-cautions-against-action).

Comment: Only the second sentence implies a lack of action to me. The first sentence says nothing about action at all. Meanwhile, the third is somewhat nonsensical and *stand there* ***is*** an action.